# Ridge on procedural mesh after render

Tags: python, rendering, mesh

I have a procedural Mesh which is working nicely. It creates all the required faces and from what I can see connects the dots correctly.

Looks arse when it renders though. The whole surface should be smooth, but there appears to be a big ridge through the render along the side of the object.

Can anyone see what is going on here? Yes there is edge code and face code in here - I have left the edge code in simply for debugging purposes.

```
import bpy
import math
import numpy as np

def pol2cart(rho, phi, sig):
    x = rho * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(sig)
    y = rho * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(sig)
    z = rho * np.cos(phi)
    return(x, y, z)


theta = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 64) # << change 64 to 256 or 512?
rotator=np.linspace(0,np.pi,32) # << change 32 to 256 or 512
theta_list=theta.tolist()
rotator_list=rotator.tolist()
theta_list.pop()
rotator_list.pop()

verts=[]
edges=[]
faces=[]
idx=0

for segment in rotator_list:
    for thing in theta_list:
        rho=1+np.cos(thing)
        x,y,z=pol2cart(rho,thing,segment)
        vert=(x,y,z)
        verts.append(vert)
lr=len(rotator_list)
for idx1 in range(lr):
    for idx2 in range(len(theta_list)-1):
        edge=(((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2),((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2)+1)
        edges.append(edge)
        if idx1 == (lr-1):
            edge2=(((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2),((len(theta_list))-idx2))
            face=(((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2),((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2)+1,len(theta_list)-idx2-1,len(theta_list)-idx2)
        else:
            edge2=(((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2),((((idx1+1))*len(theta_list))+idx2))
            face=(((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2),((idx1*len(theta_list))+idx2)+1,(((idx1+1)*len(theta_list))+idx2)+1,(((idx1+1)*len(theta_list))+idx2))
        edges.append(edge2)
        faces.append(face)
mesh=bpy.data.meshes.new("cardioid")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("cardioid",mesh)
#object.shade_smooth()

object.location=bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)

mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mesh.update()
```

[image: MY DODGY RENDER]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you post an image of the render? It would help to find a solution because we wouldn't have to spend the time rendering it for ourselves.

Comment: at 256 for both the theta and rotator linspace line in the code, I start to see smoothness happening when using "flat" rendering, but not smooth. I have to go up to 512 to see a smooth render with no ridge. This seems overkill for such a simple procedural shape.

Comment: BTW this is my first foray into procedural meshes - pls be gentle!

Comment: There is an issue with the faces at the pole. You have a set of faces that look like a "bow tie" like selecting on a clock face, 12 o'clock across to 1 then down to 7 thru the centre, across to 6, then up thru the centre again to 12. This twisted face will make smoothing or calculating normals outside behave erratically.   Instead of the `idx == lr -1` you might want to consider appending the first vert index to list after popping to make a "ring".  Kind-of example here using bmesh https://gist.github.com/batFINGER/0aff253f586a4431a0e13695c7b8cf77.

Comment: Not sure it causes the ridge (I don't get it here), but you have odd normals, half pointing in half out. The hole at the bottom and the overlapping faces at the top make calculating normals a hit and miss deal.